# I need to build an Android Function Kotlin that converts Lattitude and Longitude to a bearing from phone to that location

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors

Example funtion signature

```
fun convertLatLongToBearing(latitude : Long, Longitude : Long) : Int {
        val bearing : Int          
        /*
        convert the latitude and longitude to a bearing to the location from phone 
        as and Int between 0 - 359 representing 360 degrees of a circle 
        */
        return bearing
    }
```

I have been researching the sensors and I am pretty sure the Fusion Location from google play will tell me where the phone is.  I can't find examples of that either

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: what is your specific question? ... right now, there is nothing to answer

Comment: How to build the body of the function I have the parameters and I know what i want to return.  so in the remark block some code to complete the function.  please read the remark block it states convert latitude and longitude to a bearing to the location from the phene  as an Int between 0 - 359 representing the 360 degtrees of a circle

Comment: that is a geometry question, not a programming question ... you are asking at the wrong website

Comment: Ok I am of the understanding that there may be an api from google play that may do this I may be wrong that is why I am asking

Comment: Thanks for the edit jsotola .... just knowing that i will have to use my trig from college is a help if that is the only way.  This will be created I am just not sure how

Comment: I can do it with trig now, jsotola that is why I asked the question here, first you saw it right away that is quit remarkable  --  but also you pointed me in the right direction.